# Understanding different strategies for message handling in the Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a home project to play with DirectX and WINAPI. I just found an interesting behavior.

In the code below, if I use my `wndd->h_` (type: HWND), what was the result of `CreateWindowEx()`, in the `PeekMessage()` as second parameter, then the main loop starts to working on a single core with heavier load, while leaving the second parameter as 0, then the calculation spreads out well.

```
void WinLoop() {
    while (!wndd->exit_) {
      //if (PeekMessage(&(wndd->msg_), 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {        //NOTE : Frequently changing what core is loaded
        if (PeekMessage(&(wndd->msg_), wndd->h_, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) { //NOTE : Heavy load on one core
            TranslateMessage(&(wndd->msg_));
            DispatchMessage(&(wndd->msg_));
        }

        //TODO : update
        //TODO : draw
        //TODO : calculate statistic
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work just fine, but I can not find any information about this. What is under the hood?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx) for the `PeekMessage` function, the second parameter is…

> *hWnd* [in, optional]
>
> > Type: **HWND**
> >
> > A handle to the window whose messages are to be retrieved. The window must belong to the current thread.
> >
> > If *hWnd* is `NULL`, `PeekMessage` retrieves messages for any window that belongs to the current thread, and any messages on the current thread's message queue whose hwnd value is `NULL` (see the `MSG` structure). Therefore if hWnd is `NULL`, both window messages and thread messages are processed.
> >
> > If hWnd is -1, `PeekMessage` retrieves only messages on the current thread's message queue whose hwnd value is `NULL`, that is, thread messages as posted by `PostMessage` (when the hWnd parameter is `NULL`) or `PostThreadMessage`.

It is also important to pay attention to what the `PeekMessage` function *does*. In short, it retrieves the first message (matching the specified criteria, if applicable) that exists in the queue. Because you've specified the `PM_REMOVE` flag, it also *removes* that message from the queue.

More interesting is what happens if there are no messages for you in the queue. In that case, `PeekMessage` immediately returns false.

You now have enough information to understand the difference in behavior between the two function calls. In the first case, you're passing `NULL` as the second parameter, so the `PeekMessage` function is retrieving messages for *any* window that belongs to the current thread, as well as thread messages. In the second case, you're passing a handle to a *specific window* as the second parameter, so the `PeekMessage` function is retrieving messages *only* for that window. Because there are a lot fewer messages to retrieve for that one window, as compared to all windows and threads, the `PeekMessage` function is mostly just returning false. Little to no time is spent processing messages. And as soon as it returns false, your `while` loop kicks in, looping back to the beginning and calling the `PeekMessage` function again.

Basically, you've created a tight loop that just sits and burns CPU time, polling the `PeekMessage` function continuously without *doing* anything, which interferes with the operating system's execution scheduler. The app can still get pre-empted, of course, but you are guaranteed to use 100% of your allocated time-slice.

There is a purpose for this behavior, like when writing a game. A `PeekMessage` loop is also commonly used in applications that are doing lengthy background processing, but want to continue pumping messages to keep the UI responsive. But there is no reason to use `PeekMessage` in a normal application's message loop where you don't need real-time processing. Instead, you want the `GetMessage` function, which actually *waits* until it receives a message before returning. This is far more efficient in terms of CPU time because it isn't constantly polling. You get the time you need, but no more. [It is also much more battery-friendly](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/peekmessage-optimizing-applications-for-extended-battery-life).

I assume that, if you're playing with DirectX, you probably *are* trying to write a game or screensaver or some other quasi-real-time thing, which is why you're using the `PeekMessage` function in the first place. But you will probably want to pass `NULL` as the function's second parameter, because you want to process all window and thread messages, not just the ones for your main window.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just measuer how many iterations can burn in the CPU like this in a second. The interesting thing is the PeekMessage() condition with all the windows messages rotate faster o.O What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't see, how this answer addresses the question. In a typical DirectX application, there is usually just a single window, and the only common thread message is `WM_QUIT`. Filtering messages for this single window doesn't account for *"a lot fewer messages"* under these premises. Even if that were the case, it doesn't explain, why not filtering messages spreads CPU load across all cores.

Comment: I think if you set PeekMessage to a specific window it can do it in "one" thread. I'm the noob here guys, I'm just guessing... If you have a lot of window, the low-level stuff try to manage it with multiple threads. But... the thing is: Why the hell are the loop slower when PeekMessage has to handle "fewer" messages o.O

Comment: @NMD: Windows have thread-affinity. You can think of it as windows being owned by a thread. The message retrieval functions return messages for windows on the calling thread only. Consequently, message retrieval is inherently single-threaded. Whatever code gets spread across multiple cores, it isn't message retrieval.

Comment: I see..., thank you for this. Now I know what I have to learn ;)